# Page preventing React re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a working React component, which can be seen here.

However, when embedding this in an internal page the re-render doesn't happen, although the component's timing is still working fine (confirmed with `console.log`)

Is there anything that could potentially be blocking a re-render in a webpage?

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      number: 0
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setNumber();
  },

  setNumber: function() {
    this.setState({
      number: Math.random()
    }, () => {
      window.setTimeout(this.setNumber, 1000);
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.number}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <span><Hello name="World" /><Hello name="World" /></span>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "re-render"? There is nothing happening which would cause the component to re-render

Comment: please add the code to the question instead of linking to an external site

Comment: re-render, i.e update the page with the new number.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I suspect there is something on the integration page that is causing the code to fail. Do you see any errors in the JS console?

Comment: No exceptions at all.